# gets() causing output error

Tags: c, gets

error in  output due to gets()...as it can be seen in the image ... program prints 0 before waiting for user to enter the string. I need to read a string of "click   X" format where X is a integer. Is there any alternative to gets() to use in this situation?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,k,i;
    char action[10];
    int *open;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);                                    
    open= calloc( sizeof(int),n);               

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        open[i]=0;
    }


    for(i=0;i<k;i++)
    {                                                     
        //gets to read an input  as "click 1"
      gets(action); 
      printf("%d\t%c",i,action[6]);     
    }
    free(open);                                                         
    return 0;
}
```

[image: output of the above program....as it can be seen that instead of waiting for user to input string for action, it prints 0 .]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste it instead.

Comment: ok...thanks for suggestion

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Comment: Elaborate what? Did you read all the answers to the linked question?

Comment: i got your point.  is there any alternative for this situation?

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to do one of the things suggested in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: I am not sure if this is duplicate possible cause is calloc of int whereas gets is for char ( I may be completely wrong though )

Answer (score 1):

Your `action` is probably declared too short. Try

```
  char action[64];
```

instead.

Then replace

```
  gets(action); /// BAD CODE
```

with

```
  fflush (NULL);
  memset (action, 0, sizeof(action));
  fgets  (action, sizeof(action), stdin);
```

You should ***never* use `gets`, it is obsolete**.

<sup>(use `fflush` to flush output buffer; the `memset` is clearing the `action` buffer; the `fgets` is reading at most 63 bytes in it from `stdin`, so you are sure `action` is ending will a null byte as every C string should)</sup>

You should ask your compiler to give you all warnings and debug info, e.g. use `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

You should learn to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: The issue here is the `gets` call not asking for user input at all. Switching to `fgets` will not change that. Reading the duplicate question will.

Comment: why have you deducted 1 from sizeof(action)

Comment: @smasher: my mistake, corrected!

Answer (score 0):

After 'scanf'  use

```
getchar();
```

to consume extra newline. As 'scanf' can not discard newline, first iteration of 'gets' take the newline.

**Don't use 'gets', use 'fgets' instead**

You can use 'fgets()' as

```
fgets(action, sizeof(action), stdin);
```

Comment: True, but does not answer the question.

Comment: how to use fgets() in this situation as i am not using any  file stream?

Comment: yup, it solved the problem probably consuming extra newline

Comment: @interjay, answer edited.